# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Switching Hash Algorithm

Tags: asp.net, security

I use asp.net forms authentication to handle hashing/salting to and from plaintext passwords to the DB. This project was set up to use SHA-1 hash as the algorithm, but I am thinking about switching to something like BCrypt or PBKDF2 and was wondering how people usually make a transition like this.

Somehow I have to deal with the current passwords in the db hashed with SHA-1 and then new passwords will be hashed by something else. I could store a bit in the DB that lets me know which one it is, and then force a pw reset on everybody, but I don't know how easy this would be to do since I can't modify the forms authentication authentication code that does this for me. Also, the encrypted password field in the db may be two different column types for the two different hashes (may need a bigger column for new algorithm).

Comment: What you need is to extend the Authentication Provider and create your own instances in the wrapped data.

Comment: Why not just force everyone to update their passwords using the existing password reset mechanisms?

Comment: I agree with @jcolebrand here: If you are going to make people update their passwords then you should use the existing reset mechanism. However, this does create an additional barrier to entry which will drive some users away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first hash with the new algorithm and test to see if that matches. If it does not match then you could hash with the old algorithm and see if *that* matches. If it does then overwrite with the hashed value from the new algorithm that you computed first. This way you can gradually shift everyone to the new algorithm behind the scenes when they log in.

Also, if you are really worried that storing the older hash values is insecure, you could double-hash them with the new algorithm. So your second check would compute the hash with the old algorithm and then hash that result with the new algorithm before checking for a match.

Comment: I like the ladder approach but this is open to a DoS attack if the servers are internet facing.

Comment: @jcolebrand I see your point in that this is more resource-intensive. However, the username would still be used to determine which password to check against so if you are referring to a collision-based DoS this should be no more susceptible then a single-hash system.

Comment: no, a workload based attack. If it's known that it checks each of two hashes, they can force checks by supplying random garbage. It's twice as much work as checking a single hash. Mostly it was just a point to OP to consider.

Comment: @jcolebrand Definitely agree with you on that, though of course a single-hash system is still susceptible with enough firepower. There are steps that should be taken to reduce the risk of a DoS either way.

Comment: @jcolebrand if the cost of calculating the old hash is negligible compared to the cost of calculating the new hash, then it shouldn't be an issue. When comparing sha-1 vs bcrypt, wouldn't this be the case?

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty good point, MD5 hashing isn't that heavy is it? But then again, some people run sites on old machines with 512MB and a P4, at which point it starts to become a problem again. I was thinking more like threadpools in IIS not being configured for robustness, and him having a sudden issue with traffic spikes, but you're correct, it should be negligible at best.